# Differences in attribute order for stylesheet declaration in the HTML head

Tags: html, css, performance, syntax

Is there any difference, performance or otherwise between `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" >` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`?

I'm referring to the attribute order specifically. I realise the difference would probably be very minimal, but this is a theoretical question. I've noticed Google provides the `href` attribute first, while the HTML5 Boilerplate for instance, will put the `rel` attribute first.

Comment: What difference are you referring to? The attribute order or the difference in the path? Either way the performance difference would be so small it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: The attribute order (sorry, edited the question). I know it would probably be extremely minimal, but it's a theoretical question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't.

But it's good practice (and how it's been done previously) to define the `href` *after* the `rel` attribute.

Comment: Pure speculation, but from a code maintenance perspective it makes it more obvious you are dealing with a style sheet. Particularly if you have many in the head, it will all scan nicely at a glance. E.g : https://jsfiddle.net/n05dqw0m/

Comment: That's a good point, the href's being different sizes it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be, and if it is, it's definitely a micro-optimization. In both cases, the entire tag has to be parsed to begin to operate

Comment: I know it would probably be extremely minimal, but it's a theoretical question.

Comment: I think that if there is on any given browser, it's not guaranteed to be there on another, or on a future version.